# How do I return an HTTP 400 - Bad Request error from a web form request?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.0

The subject pretty much says it all. I have an EstateReport web form that must be called with an EstateId request parameter. I want to return an appropriate HTTP error if this parameter is not present. How do I return an HTTP error 400 as my response?

On a tangent, should I return an error if the required parameter isn't present, which I feel is more correct, or redirect to the search page for the report, which is more user friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I understand the form requires a parameter to display results in a meaningful way. A 400  is a Bad Request, while I understand your thinking, the specification states:

**"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."**

In its purest sense, if someone requests say "EstateReport.aspx" without a parameter, the server can still interpret this and reply with an appropriate response, so its not a "bad request" in its broadest sense.

What I would suggest is you detect the absence of the parameter and render an appropriate error message with a link to a page where they could select an appropriate "estateId" via some way, so when EstateReport is requested, the parameter is present.

Comment: Thanks for the input @kd7, but I am also considering the report URL being requested by a machine, so an error message should be machine readable, and a status code is machine readable.

Comment: Ahh I see... I only thought humans would be requesting the page via a browser.

Comment: So far it will be only humans, but I am often guilty of thinking ahead too much. :-) Could well be that a service requests a report, then publishes a PDF version of it to subscribers. I wouldn't want them all getting emailed a PDF version of an error message.

Answer (score 31):

you can:

```
throw new HttpException(400, "Bad Request");
```

or

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
Response.End();
```

but I'm with the same thinking as kd7 below - why not display an error message to the client letting them know what is wrong?

Comment: I had to use `new` instead of `New` before it would compile.

Comment: @Caleb It took eight years for this typo to be detected and then another month to be edited :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the HttpResponse.Status property.

Details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.status(v=vs.71).aspx