# Handling a constructor that throws in a Controller method parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making a small Asp.net Core Web API project. I have a model object that looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public readonly int Quantity;

    public Order(int quantity)
    {
        if (quantity < 0) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("quantity");
        }
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

and a controller that looks like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Order order)
    {
        // Do stuff...
        return this.StatusCode(200);
    }
}
```

If I pass an `Order` object with a positive quantity, the `Post` method works correctly. However, if I pass an `Order` with a negative quantity, the `Order` constructor throws an exception that is unhandled by my application or by asp.net.

What can I do to handle this exception in a graceful way? I notice that if I pass a request with invalid syntax (for instance, with badly formed JSON) there is no exception, and the `order` parameter has value 'null'. Can I set asp.net to do something similar? Or must I rewrite the `Order` constructor to not throw?

Comment: A quick google digged up this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling Maybe you should look at the docs first ...

Comment: Look up "web api model validation".  If your model is invalid, you should return a 400 BAD REQUEST response, not an error.  Don't use exceptions for model validation.

Comment: @CallumLinington I don't want to show a developer exception page or (necessarily) return a 400..I want to execute the method with the argument set to `null` or similar.

Comment: Read the docs, there is such things as global error handling..

Comment: @CallumLinington Sure, but in that case the method will not be executed. I don't want to fall back to a global exception handler and return a generic 'failure' message, but rather proceed into the `Post` method with the argument having value `null`, similar to what happens if the request is in an entirely invalid format. I was hoping for an answer like: "yes, you can hook into the request parsing middleware, and here's how.". Shall I take it that this is not possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166410/how-do-i-return-an-http-400-bad-request-error-from-a-web-form-request

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. If you have a model being passed to your action then you apply validation to it, you don't proceed with incorrect information.... it makes no sense! You can apply middleware to specific routes to do your model validation, or you use something like MediatR to add a strongly typed pipeline to your requests!

Comment: @Oliver: First for your use case you would need to write a custom model binder, which handles the exception and returns null instead of cancel it. But that would be bad idea anyways. It seems you are trying to use **domain model** as WebAPI Contract. **Don't do it. NEVER. It screams for trouble!** Always have a ViewModel/BindingModel/Dto for accepting and returning stuff via WebAPI

Comment: @Tseng thanks, you're right. I was trying to save code by reusing the domain model. It makes sense for a small project but I can see how it would break down as the API gets more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DataAnnotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) to do what you are doing the MVC way.

```
public class Order
{
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Order order)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }

    // Do stuff...
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The other plus side is if you ever decide to use the `Order` model in an MVC web application (with views), you will get client side validation because of the `Range` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best way to go. I was hoping to keep the exceptions-from-constructor stuff around because the model was shared with non-MVC code where that pattern made more sense, but I think it does not fit so well here.

Comment: It's not always ideal to share model code used by APIs elsewhere. Typically you define a ViewModel specifically to define the API wire format, and specify model validation on this ViewModel. Then if it's valid, map it to your underlying model type inside the controller.

Comment: @ssmith When I use the word "model" in MVC, I always mean the thing you pass to the view and not a domain model. I guess some people call it view model but I stay away from that because there is no ViewModel in MVC but it exists in mvvm. Anyhow, we are both on the same page.